# How do I force knockout to update the model from its bindings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-events

I understand that knockout normally only updates text box bindings when the control loses focus. I have a `keydown` event attached to several text boxes and the model is not updating the value from the currently focused text box. How can I force the model to update itself with the value from the textbox during the `keydown` event?

```
$('.mySelector').on('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) { // enter was pressed
     event.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'pathToCall',
       // model.Query still has the old text from before the keydown event since the
       // text box has not lost focus yet
       data: "{parameterName: " + JSON.stringify(ko.mapping.toJS(model.Query)) + "}",
       function (data) {
         model.SearchResults(data.d);
       },
       function ()  { alert('error'); }
     });
});
```

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do?  An explanation of your larger design might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `valueUpdate` option and set it to `afterkeydown`:

`<input data-bind="value: someValue, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />`

See "Additional parameters" section of [the docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try valueUpdate binding? More can be found @ http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html

Answer (score 1):

### Registering a Return Action binding handler

If you are trying to capture Enter key presses use a custom binding handler that captures it -

register a custom binding handler on the enter key press (note, the 'element' is the sending element the handler is bound to) -

```
ko.bindingHandlers.returnAction = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        $(element).keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.which === 13) {
                value(viewModel);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

and then on your input box, give it this data-bind, which is bound back to a function in your view model =

```
<input type="text" data-bind="returnAction: goGetData" />
```

and in the view model -

```
var goGetData = function () {
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'pathToCall',
       // model.Query still has the old text from before the keydown event since the
       // text box has not lost focus yet
       data: "{parameterName: " + JSON.stringify(ko.mapping.toJS(model.Query)) + "}",
       function (data) {
         model.SearchResults(data.d);
       },
       function ()  { alert('error'); }
     });
};
```

### Why it's different from the other answers

The other answers are not wrong if you are trying to update an observable based off of your input box, but if you are trying to attach a return action handler this answer is more correct.